# Access target object of droppable element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to know if there is a way to access the target object without using selector 'this' for example:

```
$('.target').on('drop', function(event, ui){
 var drag = ui.helper;
 var target = $(this);
});
```

I know I can assign the drag with the ui helper but is there a param for the drop target too in this context or is using 'this' the only way to assign the drop target? I couldn't see an option for this int he jQuery API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `event.target` like

```
$('.target').on('drop', function(event, ui){
 var drag = ui.helper;
 var target = $(event.target);
});
```